# How to handle NOT NULL SQL Server columns in Access forms elegantly?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have an MS Access front-end linked to a SQL Server database.

If some column is required, then the natural thing to do is to include `NOT NULL` in that column's definition (at the database level).  But that seems to create problems on the Access side. When you bind a form to that table, the field bound to that column ends up being pretty un-user-friendly.  If the user erases the text from that field, they will not be able to leave the field until they enter something.  Each time they try to leave the field while it's blank, they will get this error:

> You tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not a Variant data type.

That's a really terrible error message - even for a developer, let alone the poor user.  Luckily, I can silence it or replace it with a better message with some code like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    If DataErr = 3162 Then
        Response = acDataErrContinue
        <check which field is blank>
        MsgBox "<some useful message>"
    End If
End Sub
```

But that's only a partial fix. Why shouldn't the user be able to leave the field? No decent modern UI restricts focus like that (think web sites, phone apps, desktop programs - anything, really).  How can we get around this behavior of Access with regard to required fields?

I will post the two workarounds I have found as an answer, but I am hoping there are better ways that I have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing backend table definitions or trying to "trick" Access with out-of-sync linked table definitions, instead just change the control(s) for any "NOT NULL" column **from a bound to an unbound field** (i.e. *Clear the `ControlSource` property* and change the control name--by adding a prefix for example--to avoid annoying collisions with the underlying field name.).

This solution will definitely be less "brittle", but it will require you to manually add binding code to a number of other Form events.  To provide a consistent experience as other Access controls and forms, I would at least implement `Form_AfterInsert(), Form_AfterUpdate(), Form_BeforeInsert(), Form_BeforeUpdate(), Form_Current(), Form_Error(), Form_Undo()`.

---

P.S. Although I do not recall seeing such a poorly-worded error message before, the overall behavior described is identical for an Access table column with `Required = True`, which is the Access UI equivalent of `NOT NULL` column criteria.

Comment: I appreciate this suggestion.  It is interesting but seems complex.  I'm not entirely sure what I'd put in each of those event handlers.  Could you elaborate or point me to a good resource?

Comment: I'm not able to provide detailed code now, but the overall concept is that the control needs to be explicitly loaded and saved and validated in the code.  For example, in OnCurrent() there should be something like `txtID.Value = Me.ID` assuming that the column ID is selected in the Form's RecordSource query.  Honestly, there are so many details to consider and control properties to set/validate, that the overall technique is beyond answers to this question.  In this case, "elegant" does not mean quick or easy.

Comment: For the record, let me emphasize that this is the proper way to go about changing the default behavior of Access forms.  Other tricks will likely end up requiring extra code anyway, maintenance problems or buggy forms.

Comment: A trough answer. It is either your suggestion or you go all in with nulls for the default sql server side (all text columns allow nulls). For a small application your suggest can work. For a large application, then adopting nulls sql server side will be much less work. I don't have a pretty answer here.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal  I agree that allowing nulls on the backend can sometimes work, but I was answering not only the overall question, but specifically the OP's own answer which contained only bad tricks for fooling default Access Form validation.  For a large application, a better suggestion is to choose something other than Access, especially if the Forms do not behave in an acceptable manner... but that's what I already suggested in comments to the OP.  I cringe at weakening the backend just to satisfy a poor UI.  It is possible to enforce good backend data rules and have a great UI also.

Comment: My vb.net and my asp.net applications follow this standard and suggestion. The MAJOR beef and argument to not allow nulls is because it supposed is a pain for developers. But then there is date columns (lots of nulls) and ANY left join (which as I claim is about 80% of them), then  you again have tons of null columns. You going to HAVE to deal with nulls everywhere in a application. So as a developer one is far better off to assume and take a design choice that does NOT have ZLS strings all over the place. I find ZLS far worse of a issue. My suggesting is not limited to Access applications.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest if you can simply change all tables on sql server to allow nulls for those text columns. For bit, number columns default them to 0 sql server side. While our industry tends to suggest to avoid nulls, and many a developer ALSO wants to avoid nulls, so they un-check the allow nulls SQL server side. The problem is you can never run away and avoid tons of nulls anyway. Take a simple query of say customers and their last invoice number + invoice total. But of course VERY common would be to include customers that not bought anything in that list (customers without ivoices yet, or customers without any of a gazillion possible cases where the child record(s) don't yet exist. I find about 80% or MORE of my quires in a typical application are LEFT joins. So that means any parent record without child records will return ALL OF those child columns as null. You going to work with, and see, and HAVE to deal with tons and tons of nulls in a application EVEN if you table designs NEVER allow nulls. You cannot avoid them - you simply cannot run away from those nasty nulls.

Since one will see lots of nulls in code and any sql query (those VERY common left joins), then by far and away the best solution is to simply allow and set all text columns as allowing nulls. I can also much state that if an application designer does not put their foot down and make a strong choice to ALWAYS use nulls, then the creeping in of both NULLS and ZLS data is a much worse issue to deal with.

The problem and issue becomes very nasty and painful if one does not have control or one cannot make this choice.

At the end of the day, Access simply does not work with SQL server and the choice of allowing ZLS columns.

For a migration to sql server (and I been doing them for 10+ years), it is without question that going will nulls for all text columns is by far and away the most easy choice here.

So I recommend that you not attempt to code around this issue but simply change all your sql tables to default to and allow nulls for empty columns.

The result of above may require some minor modifications to the application, but the pain and effort is going to be far less then attempting to fix or code around Access poor support (actually non support) of ZLS columns when working with SQL server.

I will also note that this suggesting is not a great suggestion, but it is simply the best suggestion given the limitations of how Access works with SQL server. Some database systems (oracle) do have a overall setting that says every null is to be converted to ZLS and thus you don't have to care about say this:

```
select * from tblCustomers where (City is null) or (City is = "")
```

As above shows, the instant you allow both ZLS and nulls into your application is the SAME instant that you created a huge monster mess. And the scholarly debate about nulls being un-defined is simply a debate for another day.

If you are developing with Access + SQL server, then one needs to adopt a standard approach - I recommend that approach simply is that all text columns are set to allows nulls, and date columns. For numbers and bit columns, default them to 0.

This comes down to which is less pain and work.
Either attempet some MAJOR modifications to the application and say un-bind text columns (that can be a huge amount of work).

Or

Simply assume and set all text columns to allow nulls. It is the lessor of a evil in this case, and one has to conform to the bag of tools that has been handed to you.

So I don't have a workaround, but only a path and course to take that will result in the least amount of work and pain. That least pain road is to go with allowing nulls. This suggestion will only work of course if one can make that choice.

Answer (score -1):

The two workarounds I have come up with are:

1. Don't make the database column `NOT NULL` and rely exclusively on Access forms for data integrity rather than the database.  Readers of that table will be burdened with an ambiguous column that will not contain nulls in practice (as long as the form-validation code is sound) but could contain nulls in theory due to the way the column is defined within the database. Not having that 100% guarantee is bothersome but may be good enough in reality.

   > **Verdict**: easy but sloppy - proceed with caution
2. Abuse the fact that Access' links to external tables have to be refreshed manually.  Make the column `NULL` in SQL Server, refresh the link in Access, and then make the column `NOT NULL` again in SQL Server - but this time, don't refresh the link in Access.

   The result is that Access won't realize the field is `NOT NULL` and, therefore, will leave the user alone.  They can move about the form as desired without getting cryptic error 3162 or having their focus restricted.  If they try to save the form while the field is still blank, they will get an ODBC error stemming from the underlying database.  Although that's not desirable, it can be avoided by checking for blank fields in `Form_BeforeUpdate()` and providing the user with an intelligible error message instead.

   > **Verdict**: better for data integrity but also more of a pain to maintain, sort of hacky/astonishing, and brittle in that if someone refreshes the table link, the dreaded error / focus restriction will return - then again, that worst-case scenario isn't catastrophic because the consequence is merely user annoyance, not data-integrity problems or the application breaking

Comment: Before tweaking the back end to make the front end work, I would suggest choosing an alternative front end... abandon Access if the UI is so bad that you consider weakening good design.  If you are new to Access and already can't tolerate such behavior, you will likely find many other poorly-designed features contrary to "decent modern UI design".  (BTW, I completely agree with your description of the behavior, so when Access was required at one point at my job, it took me a long time to get over fighting the Access-esque UI design.  I'm just trying to save you the heartache.)

Comment: @CPerkins Yeah, I'm with you.  Unfortunately, I'm stuck with Access for the moment since it's a large, preexisting application that I don't have time to rebuild from scratch.

Comment: Allowing ZLS AND nulls is a nightmware. Unless new record code always sets all those columns as ZLS then you are screwed. Typical CRUD form will not edit or even have all of the columns for editing. So now you add and tons of  columns will be null and tons  ZLS.  Adopting a coding standard for empty columns are always null is a FANTASTIC way to go. SQL don't have a setting like Oracle to make all nulls as ZLS. Your attempt to runaway from nulls will fail the first time you do a very common left join This will result in the child rows all being null and thus you coding for nulls anyway.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Let me clarify.  The column is not meant to contain either nulls or zero-length strings.  The field is **required** on the form.  Therefore, debating whether it is better to represent blanks as nulls or zero-length strings is not relevant. Plus, I never said it was a string field - that was your assumption.  The question is simply this: given a form with a required column, how do you give the user a good validation experience instead of unpleasantly restricting focus to that field while it is blank - a strange quirk I've never seen outside of MS Access.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I just updated my answer to clarify it a bit and also updated the question to make it clear that it's a required column.  Hopefully you don't still consider it downvote-worthy (if that was you).

Comment: I did not downvote. It is a nasty issue with Access. The recommend to avoid nulls as you say is a debate for scholars and is debate for another day. To me empty columns are null - end of story.One needs to adopt a standard for their given application. So for practical real world applications it best to assume any and all empty columns are saved as nulls - this is especially the case with Access + SQL server applications. Access + SQL server simply does not work well with ZLS. Downside of ZLS + Null creeping into a application is a nightmare. Any left join will introduce lots of nulls anyway.

Comment: One needs to adopt a standard and everything is either ZLS or nulls. However WHEN working with Access if one CAN make a choice, then all empty as nulls is for sure the way to go.  Working and migrating Access to SQL server for 10+ years hands down making the assumption and choice that all empty columns allow nulls is the best choice. For number columns, bit, then I default them to 0. But for text columns, simply null is best. The problem is when one does not have a choice.  My only suggesting here is to go all in with nulls. If one can't do that then they are in for a very rough ride.